# Microsoft ODBC for Oracle error for a simple data extraction in Excel

Tags: windows, excel, oracle, vba, oracle11g

the problem that I'm coming across is the **Microsoft ODBC for Oracle** error.

The code conducts a simple extraction of data. Assume a 5x5 matrix in excel which becomes populated.

So I'm running this VBA code that was developed probably 10+ years ago. I run that code on a laptop with the following configuration and it works **fine**:

- 32bit Windows 7 Enterprise
- Oracle 11g 64bit release 11.2.0.4.0 Enterprise Edition
- Microsoft Office Suite 2010 32bit Professional

When I run the same code (nothing changed within the code) on a different machine with the following specification, it fails and a dialog box pops up with the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle error:

- 64bit Windows 7 Enterprise
- Oracle 12c 64bit release 12.1.0.1.0
- Microsoft Office Suite 2013 32bit Professional

I have tried to install the same version of Oracle 11g and the Office suite as the laptop but it still fails.
This is the error that I get.
[image]

Could someone please shed some light as to why this happens?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you have the 64-bit version of the Oracle client software installed. Have you tried installing the 32-bit version too? If you have 32-bit Office then you probably need the 32-bit Oracle components to go along with it.

Comment: I haven't installed the 32bit version yet. I can give that a shot

Comment: It didn't work. I got the same error